# I am connecting to the C# server with a Java client, but I am unable to send data

Tags: java, c#

I have created an asynchronous server with C#, and connecting clients can send and receive data successfully. However, the client I developed using Java in Android Studio can connect and even send data, but it cannot receive data from the C# server, and there are no log outputs.

What puzzles me the most is that when I create a server using Packet Sender, my Android Studio application can both send and receive data, but when I prepare a server with C#, there is no output on the Android Studio side.

[image: Screenshot]

c# server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace EsnafKuryem
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        public static Dictionary<int, Client> users = new Dictionary<int, Client>();
        public static int MaxClient = 50;
        public class Client
        {

            public int id;
            public TCP tcp;
            public Client(int _id)
            {
                id = _id;
                tcp = new TCP(_id);
            }
            public class TCP
            {
                public int id;
                public Socket soket;
                public static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    public TCP(int _id)
                      {
                    id = _id;
                       }
                    public  void Connect(Socket sokets)
                    {
                    soket = sokets;
                    Console.WriteLine("Bağlantı Geldi");
                    soket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, Yaz, null);
                    }
                public  void Yaz(IAsyncResult result)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int say = soket.EndReceive(result);
                        if (say<=0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Client Cıktı");
                            return;
                        }
                        byte[] data = new byte[say];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, data, say);
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                        var datas = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sa");
                        soket.Send(data);
                    
                        soket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, Yaz, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Client cıktı");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                public void Send(string veri)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(veri);
                        soket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None,SendSon,null);
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                public void SendSon(IAsyncResult result)
                {
                    soket.EndSend(result);
                }
            }
           
            
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= MaxClient; i++)
            {
                users.Add(i, new Client(i));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sunucu Başlatılıyor..");
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5555));
            server.Listen(10);
            server.BeginAccept(Baglanti, null);
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= MaxClient; i++)
                {
                    if (users[i].tcp.soket != null)
                    {
                        string ve = Console.ReadLine();
                        users[i].tcp.Send(ve);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Baglanti(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Socket soket = server.EndAccept(result);
            server.BeginAccept(Baglanti, null);
            for (int i = 1; i <= MaxClient; i++)
            {
                if (users[i].tcp.soket == null)
                {
                    users[i].tcp.Connect(soket);

                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sunucu Doldu");
        }
    }
}
```

Android Studio java client

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    Socket soket;
    InputStream input;
    DataOutputStream out;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        new Thread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    soket = new Socket("192.168.1.87",5555);
                    new Thread(new Al()).start();
                }catch (IOException e){

                }
            }
        })).start();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Send("Özkan PALA")).start();

            }
        });
    }

    class Send implements Runnable{

        String veris;
        Send(String veri){
            veris = veri;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(soket.getOutputStream()));

                out.write(veris.getBytes());
                System.out.println(veris);
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());

            }
        }

    }

    class Al implements Runnable{

        public void run(){
            try {
                input = soket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                String receivedData = reader.readLine();
                while ((receivedData = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Alınan veri: " + receivedData);
                }

                System.out.println("Alınan veri: ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Alınan veris: " + e);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

All permissions have been granted in the Android Studio application.

I can send and receive data to my client using the Packet Sender program. However, when I prepare the server with C#, data is coming from the Android device, but the data I send from the C# server doesn't reach the Android device.

The C# server works fine with a C# client, but it doesn't receive data with the Java client.

Comment: Your forgot to translate the title, and also please remove the salutation.